# Cambiar de color el icono de p-autoComplete Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng

Estoy utilizando primeNG y la propiedad p-autoComplete, tengo los estilos definidos, pero no logro cambiar el color azul que viene por defecto a uno rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el styleclass en tu componente de autoComplete para agregar las clases de css que quieras y a parte no olvidar agregar la propiedad de encapsulation con el valor none en tu componente donde estes usando el autoComplete de primeng para que esta tenga acceso a las clases de tu archivo de css.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 template: '<p-autoComplete tyleClass="button-pg"></p-autoComplete>',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {}

 //---------- app.component.scss ------------//
 .button-pg {
   button {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: black;
   }
 }
 //------------------------------------------//
```